# Accessing variable template using decltype

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

A minimized example of my code showing the problem:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
const std::map<std::string, T> smap;

template <>
const std::map<std::string, bool> smap<bool>{{"a", false}};

int main() {
    std::map<bool, std::string> rmap{{false, "x"}};

    for (const auto& [key, val] : rmap) {
        std::cerr << typeid(bool).hash_code() << "\n";
        std::cerr << typeid(decltype(key)).hash_code() << "\n";

        std::cerr << smap<bool>.size() << "\n";
        std::cerr << smap<decltype(key)>.size() << "\n";

        assert((std::is_same_v<bool, decltype(key)>));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nxcxf74GY)

It gives the output:

```
10838281452030117757
10838281452030117757
1
0
example.cpp:22: int main(): Assertion `(std::is_same_v<bool, decltype(key)>)' failed.
```

Why is it that I can't access the variable template using `decltype` when it's referring to the same type (`bool`)?

For the record I also tried to not use structured binding and using decltype on first in the pair with the same result.

However if I create an actual bool variable, like so ...

```
bool b;
std::cerr << settings_map<decltype(b)>.size() << "\n";
```

... it's working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decltype(key)` is `const bool`, not `bool`. And [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) strips const qualifiers, so the two have the same (runtime) representation.

> If the type of type or expression is cv-qualified, the result of the typeid refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the cv-unqualified type (that is, `typeid(const T) == typeid(T)`).

So while `typeid` treats the two types as equivalent, template expansion (and `is_same_v`) does not, and you get two different maps: one for `bool` and one for `const bool`. Note that the assertion

```
assert((std::is_same_v<const bool, decltype(key)>));
```

succeeeds if put in place of the one in your code. To remove cv-qualifiers, use [`remove_cv_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cv).

```
std::cerr << settings_map<std::remove_cv_t<decltype(key)>>.size() << "\n";
```

In your last snippet

```
bool b;
std::cerr << settings_map<decltype(b)>.size() << "\n";
```

The `b` is *not* constant, so `decltype(b)` is actually `bool`, not `const bool`.

Comment: Right - makes sense, I thought typeid would include const, good to know.

Comment: @Zitrax Yeah, the problem is `typeid` is very *old* C++, designed as an incredibly rudimentary form of reflection before we had a lot of this fancy template stuff. So it doesn't always interact with more complex features in C++'s type system.

Comment: @Zitrax I'd say `typeid` return the same for `const` is by design (even for current standard), it'd be strange a `const` reference return different id than what it refers to. (and `typeid` also remove all reference)

Answer (score 2):

the `value_type` is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, so `decltype(key)` is `const bool`, not `bool`

and you capture it by `const auto&` so it's `const` anyway

---

---

`typeid` remove all cvref qualifiers, that's why you get same `hash_code`

as a side note, `hash_code` is a *hash* and no guaranteed on they would not collide, you can use `operator==` to check type equality.

Answer (score 2):

Keys are `const` so you'll need to remove it to make the assertion pass.

```
assert((std::is_same_v<bool, std::remove_cv_t<decltype(key)>>));
```